# Comma separated list in hive becomes two columns when sending output to csv

Tags: sql, csv, hive, sh

I have a table in hive which has a list in it - created using collect_set. When I query the table and send the output to a csv file the list becomes different columns instead of one column.

query

```
 hive - e "Select col1 from table" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > output.csv
```

The current csv ouput has two columns like this

```
  col1         col2
 ["Apple"      "Mango"]
 ["Apple"      "Pineapple"]
 ["Orange"     "Mango"]
 ["Apple"      "Mango"]
```

How can I have my file output is as one column col1:

```
 col1
 ["Apple","Mango"]
 ["Apple","Pineapple"]
 ["Orange","Mango"]
 ["Apple","Mango"]
```

Comment: What you are doing looks correct.  Your `sed` substitution looks good.  I don't understand how the output is giving you 2 columns when you are querying 1 though...

Comment: I am sending my output to a csv file and this is where it becomes two columns. If I do a command line output of the hql directly or query via hue where I convert it to excel - I have no issues getting it as a list. However, I need to convert to a csv file via command line as it is part of my general workflow

Comment: I'm am still a bit confused.  Your desired output is still 2 columns with 1 column heading (unless there are tabs in your data?).  After passing your "current csv" through the provided `sed` command, you will get something close to what is desired.  I will post the result as an answer so I can put it in a code block...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I may not have communicated the question well. I have rewritten for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output of your command on the "current csv":

```
col1,       col2
["Apple",   "Mango"]
["Apple",   "Pineapple"]
["Orange",   "Mango"]
["Apple",   "Mango"]
```

Between each field, you had a tab and 3 spaces.  So the spaces are not going to be substituted as commas.  If you are simply trying to remove the extra space in there as well you can try

```
hive - e "Select col1 from table" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' | sed 's/ *//g'  > output.csv
```

Output:

```
col1,col2
["Apple","Mango"]
["Apple","Pineapple"]
["Orange","Mango"]
["Apple","Mango"]
```

Not sure if this is what you want, but this will remove the extra spaces.  You will still have two column headings.  In a comma delimited file, your columns are separated by commas, so this is still 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this using hive query

```
hive - e "Select concat_ws('\\;',col1) as col1 from table" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > output.csv
```

I separated the elements in the list using semicolons